# How to test whether an interface{} is a map without knowing key/value types?

Tags: go

Although it is possible to test whether an `interface{}` is a map of known key/value type:

```
func TypeTest(thing interface{}) {
    switch thing.(type) {
    case map[string]string:
        fmt.Println("map string string")
    case map[string]interface{}:
        fmt.Println("map string")
    case map[interface{}]interface{}:
        fmt.Println("map")
    case interface{}:
        fmt.Println("interface")
    default:
        fmt.Println("unknown")
    }
}
TypeTest(map[string]string{"a": "1"}) // "map string string"
TypeTest(map[string]int{"a": 1}) // "interface" !!!
```

But what if I just want to know whether an `interface{}` is a map or not, without worrying about its key/value type?

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/6hm_ZxZDmZ

Comment: I think you got it, deemok,thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `reflect` package for this.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]int)

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", isMap(m))
}

func isMap(m interface{}) bool {
    rt := reflect.TypeOf(m)
    return rt.Kind() == reflect.Map
}
```